# Separating a shapefile into separate shapefile based upon their features using a python script

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, shapefile, clip

I have a shapefile of a US. I need to make an individual shapefile for all the states in the US using a python in ArcGIS. How can I do it?

Comment: For every state, or just one?

Comment: for every state

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of the states you can do something similar to the following:

```
import arcpy

statelist = [row.getValue('STATE_NAME') for row in arcpy.SearchCursor("INPUT DATASET")]

for state in statelist:
    arcpy.Select_analysis("INPUT DATASET", str(state), '[STATE_NAME] = "' + str(state) + '"')
```

Comment: Do i have to write the name of all the 52 states in the statelist ?

Comment: You can use this: statelist = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ("NAME))]

Comment: For 10.0 you cannot use the 'da' option on the search cursor - so this will work: statelist = [row.getValue('STATE_NAME') for row in arcpy.SearchCursor("INPUT DATASET")]

Answer (score 1):

I would loop through each feature in the FC and write the geometry to a new FC.

```
import arcpy

# This is a path to an ESRI FC of the USA
states = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\TemplateData\TemplateData.gdb\USA\states'
out_path = r'C:\temp'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(states, ["STATE_NAME", "SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        out_name = str(row[0]) # Define the output shapefile name (e.g. "Hawaii")
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(row[1], out_path, out_name)
```